# Changing the cursor while it's not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor

so I have a webapplication (in html,css and javascript, jquery) that drags an element around (meaning, the cursor doesn't move over that element since the element is moving with the cursor). I wish to change the cursor to a 'move' cursor, but I'm encountering this weird behaviour. I wrote this bit of code to demonstrate:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <script>
        var b=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        b.onmousedown=function(event){
            if(event.button){
                b.style.cursor='move';
            }
        }
        b.onmouseup=function(event){
            if(event.button){
                b.style.cursor='initial';
            }               
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically, I want the cursor to changing to 'cursor:move;' whenever the user is holding the right mouse button; But, the following happens:

- **initial:** cursor: default
- **mouse down:** cursor: default
- **mouse move:** cursor: default
- **mouse up:** cursor: move
- **mouse move:** cursor: default

so now my question is: why does this happen, and what would be a good way to fix it?

*PS:* tested in chrome, this is the main browser I need this to work in

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/vepihik/edit?html,css,js,output

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseAction)
document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseAction)

function onMouseAction(e){
    document.body.style.cursor = e.buttons && e.button == 2 ? 'move' : 'default';        
}
```

```css
html, body{ height:100%; }
```

```html
Try to hold the RIGHT mouse button and move it, then release
```

Attaching the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events on the document itself and making them both call the same function which simply check the button clicked. `right = 2` in your case.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to reset the cursor to the default style when the mouse button is released. `e.button == 2` will always be the case here, because it is the same button. It needs a differentiation by event _type_.

Comment: It simply changes back to the default cursor because the context menu is opened. If you add `oncontextmenu="return false;"` to the `body` your snippet doesn't work anymore

Comment: @vrugtehagel -  opps sorry I edited it and it got messed up. I will edit again!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach `mousedown` and `mouseup` events to initiate functions which will change and revert the cursor.

Within each function you can confirm that the button just pressed (or released) is the right mouse button.

**Working Example:**

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

function changeCursorToMove(event) {
 if ((event.which === 3) || (event.button === 2)) {
        div.classList.add('move-cursor');
    }
}

function changeCursorToDefault(event) {
 if ((event.which === 3) || (event.button === 2)) {
        div.classList.remove('move-cursor');
    }
}

div.addEventListener('mousedown', changeCursorToMove, false);
div.addEventListener('mouseup', changeCursorToDefault, false);

document.oncontextmenu = function(){return false;}
```

```css
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
}

.move-cursor {
cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: why did you bother answering well after I gave almost identical answer, which fits more to what OP wants? I'm trying to understand the logic of you wasting your time

Comment: I wasn't on this page when I was working out the solution. Once I'd got the solution working to my satisfaction, I came back to this page and posted it. In the meantime you had posted your solution. I agree our approaches are very similar. I'd say that's probably a good thing.

Comment: it took you an hour? and you posted it anyway even if it was duplicate?

Comment: It took me about 10mins. I'm guessing you're a programmer.

Comment: Oddly enough your snippet is working, but when I put your scripts and stylesheet in a new .html file, I'm not getting the same behaviour.

Comment: @vrugtehagel - why oddly enough? and why didn't you mark my answer as the correct one? it's exactly what you wanted.

Comment: I'm not marking it as the correct answer, because it's not working for me. Oddly enough, because, your snippet shouldn't be much different from a separate local html file with a `<style>` and `<script>` tag in it. (FYI, I'm using Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87 on windows 10)

Comment: @vrugtehagel - impossible it's not working for you. it works on all browsers. I've checked it. you should **verify**. I've spent my time helping you and it does work.

Comment: I've just restarted my computer and opened the same file. It's working now, so I suppose that the problem was in the browser, not my code. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @vsync funny though that you didn't even bother to try my own code because there's nothing wrong with it and it's working just as yours does - that'd have saved you some time

Comment: @vrugtehagel - I wrote my code in 1 minute. took me more time to write the answer itself than the code. also, I like how to teach writing better code and not just code which works.